# How to group data from a file using Julia language

Tags: file, julia

Here’s my code :

```
  findFrame = findall(x->occursin("frame =",x),objet)
  sframe = []
  for i in findFrame
     lframe = objet[i]
     sframe = [sframe;split(lframe,r"frame =| --> ")[2]]
  end
  return sframe 
end

cd("C:/Users/L1028071/Documents")
for f in readdir()
  out=open("FilteredFile.txt","w")
   file = readlines(f)
   findWindow = findall(x->occursin("Window",x),file)
   for line in findWindow
     if startswith(split(file[line]," --> ")[2],"Window")
        write(out,file[line])
          write(out,"\n")
     end
  end
  close(out)
  fichier = open("FilteredFile.txt") do file
  f = readlines(file)
  WindowType = TypeFrame(f)
  end    
end
```

With this code I read all the files in my directory, for each file I only keep a few lines ( if startswith(split(file[line]," --> ")[2], “Window” …) that I will then write in a new text file (FilteredFile.txt). Once I’ve done that, I open this new file and apply a function that gives me an array.
Each time a new file from the directory is processed the file “FilteredFile.txt” is “overwritten” and then recreated with new data.

For example if I have two files in my directory I will get 2 distincts arrays :

```
Any[" ‘DataManager’", " ‘LauncherFrame’", " ‘DataManager’", " ‘DataManager’", " ‘DataManager’", " ‘ToolBox’", " ‘ToolBox’", " ‘ToolBox’", " ‘MonoWellInterpretationView’", " ‘MonoWellInterpretationView’", " ‘MonoWellInterpretationView’", " ‘MonoWellInterpretationView’", " ‘MonoWellInterpretationView’", " ’ ‘ToolBox’", " ‘DataManager’", " ‘DataManager’"]
Any[" ‘DataManager’", " ‘LauncherFrame’", " ‘DataManager’", " ‘DataManager’", " ‘DataManager’", " ‘ToolBox’", " ‘ToolBox’", " ‘ToolBox’", " ‘MonoWellInterpretationView’", " ‘MonoWellInterpretationView’", " ‘MonoWellInterpretationView’", " ‘MonoWellInterpretationView’", " ‘MonoWellInterpretationView’", , " ‘MonoWellInterpretationView’", " ‘MonoWellInterpretationView’", " ‘MonoWellInterpretationView’", " ‘MonoWellInterpretationView’", " ‘ToolBox’", " ‘DataManager’", " ‘DataManager’"]
```

I would like for any number of files in my directory to get a single array that contains the data of all the files.

I have already succeeded by not “overwriting” the “FilteredFile.txt” file each time a new file in the directory is processed. It works well when I only have 2 files in my directory but if I have 1000 I will end up with a huge “FilteredFile.txt” with thousands of lines which will take a long time to process.

So my problem is to keep overwriting the “FilteredFile.txt” file while “adding” somewhere the data of each file as we go along to have only one array.

I don’t know if I’ve made it clear and I thank you in advance for your answers and your help !

Answer (score 2):

Its not easy to help you without a reproducible piece of code - It appears that you have cut off parts of the first function (is this relevant at all?), and the reader doesn't know what a `TypeFrame` or `WindowType` is. You state its a performance problem and as such you should first try to pin down what exactly is slow for 1000 files.

You might get better performance if you do everything in one go and use a function as opposed to operate in the global scope.

```
function filterfiles(fileout, srcdir)
    open(fileout, "w") do out
        for file in readdir(srcdir)
            foreach(readlines(file)) do line
                if occursin("Windows", line) && startswith(split(line, " --> ")[2], "Windows")
                    write(out, line, "\n")
                end
            end
        end
    end
end

filterfiles("FilteredFile.txt", ".")

fichier = open("FilteredFile.txt") do file
    WindowType = TypeFrame(readlines(file))
end
```